# iOS - How to test IAP receipt validation from your server?

Tags: python, ios, swift, in-app-purchase

When you want to validate IAP Receipts with the App Store as stated in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1), you have to write some validating function in your server to do so. I am talking about the red part in this graphic :

[image]

Well, to be able to fully write the needed code on server-side, you need to have receipts to perform the test. If you look at the above graphic, it is pretty obvious.

However the only way I know to get receipts, is by requesting one from the iOS application (using the Apple SDK).

This means that if I wanted a server-side engineer to work on this validation function, I would need to request receipts with my app, and copy paste those to him so he can test... It is a slow and inefficient process... And that would make impossible to write automatic tests for it !

So how can I consistently test that validating server-side function without having to manually requests receipts with iOS app ?

Comment: You only need to capture one receipt. It will always be valid   It will be more complex if you want to validate a subscription is valid “now” but you can just hard code a date into your test rather than using the current date